# Custom Post Type URL Rewriting

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, url-rewriting, parameter

I would like to add parameter to custom post type posts

So I need to do my url like that.
http://www.mywebsite.com/mycpt-slug/post-slug/myparameter

I found this solution but here it's work with post ID, how can I do this to work whit post id?

[Why does rewrite rule work for page not for custom post type post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169710/why-does-rewrite-rule-work-for-page-not-for-custom-post-type-post)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
$newrules = array('cpt-slug/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&post_type=cpt_name&member_view=$matches[2]');
$rules = $newrules + $rules;
return $rules;
```

}

You just need to change 'p' to 'name'